# Alteração de uma tabela

Tags: sql-server

Existe a possibilidade de alterar um campo de uma tabela sem que eu perda os dados que foram anteriormente inseridos?
Tenho uma tabela que possui um campo `varchar` e que preciso alterá-lo para `int`. Ele já possui dados inseridos do tipo `varchar`.

Comment: Se todos os dados podem ser convertidos para int, não vejo problemas. Agora se você tiver caracteres não numéricos, não será possível.

Comment: Procure na ajuda do SQL por "ALTER COLUMN"

Comment: Como @Pagotti comentou, você pode usar o comando `alter table`, porém se algum dado não puder ser convertido irá gerar um erro (tamanho, ou algum caractere não numérico) . A melhor maneira de fazer isso seria criar uma tabela temporária com a mesma estrutura, mas com o campo já no tipo `int` e tentar inserir os dados lá antes pra ver se está tudo ok.

Comment: @FlavioRodrigues: A coluna a ser modificada é chave estrangeira de outra tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas abordagens para o que solicita. Sugiro que faça backup da tabela (ou do banco de dados), antes de iniciar os procedimentos.

O procedimento que segue é um esboço e não foi testado. Sugiro que primeiro teste em banco de dados de desenvolvimento.

```
nomebanco -> nome do banco de dados
tbDados -> nome da tabela
nomecoluna -> nome da coluna a alterar o tipo de dados
chaveprimaria -> coluna(s) que identifica, de forma única, cada linha da tabela
```

**(1)** O primeiro passo é verificar se todo o conteúdo da coluna pode ser convertido de *string* para numérico.

```
-- código #1
SELECT chaveprimária. nomecoluna
  from tbDados
  where isNumeric(nomecoluna) <> 1;
go
```

Caso a consulta acima retorne alguma linha, analise a informação e corrija-a.
Somente execute os próximos passos após você ter certeza de que a coluna a ser modificada possui valor numérico (ou ausência de informação - NULL) em todas as linhas.

**(2)** Coloque o banco de dados em modo restrito.

```
-- código #2
ALTER DATABASE nomebanco RESTRICTED_USER;
go
```

**(3)** 
Criar uma tabela temporária, contendo somente a chave primária da tabela e a coluna a ser alterada, já no formato numérico.

```
-- código #3 v3
SELECT chaveprimaria, convert(int, nomecoluna) as nomecoluna
  into tbDados2
  from tbDados;
go
```

**(4)** Alterar o tipo de dados da coluna. Acrescente as restrições que julgar necessárias (por exemplo, NOT NULL).

```
-- código #5
ALTER TABLE tbDados ALTER COLUMN nomecoluna int;
go
```

**(5)** Insira a informação na coluna, já no formato numérico.

```
-- código #6
UPDATE T1
  set nomecoluna= T2.nomecoluna
  from tbDados as T1
       inner join tbDados2 as T2 on T1.chaveprimaria = T2.chaveprimaria;
go
```

**(6)** Verifique se a conversão foi correta. Tendo certeza de que está tudo correto, libere o banco de dados e apague a tabela temporária.

```
-- código #7
DROP TABLE tbDados2;
ALTER DATABASE nomebanco MULTI_USER;
go
```

---

Sugestão de leitura:
[Modify Columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/modify-columns-database-engine)